# Magento 2: How to add multiple locally stored fonts?

Tags: magento2, css, design, fonts

I want add one locally stored font in my custom theme folder. I followed the instructions here:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/using-fonts.html

But the following code makes my store loads with **no styles at all**:

```
.lib-font-face(
    @family-name:'myfontname',
    @font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/myfontname',
    @font-weight: normal,
    @font-style: normal
)
```

Why does this code break all styles?
And if this code is used to add **one** custom font, how to add **two or more** fonts locally stored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've followed DevDocs then you'll have `_typography.less` where you've defined your font by using `.lib-font-face mixin`. Now to use that font you can override @font-family-name__base variable by either declaring it in _themes.less file or in _variables.less files in your custom theme.
so you'll end up with something like

```
@font-family-name__base:'myfontname';
@font-family__base: @font-family-name__base, @font-family__sans-serif;
```

**To add multiple fonts**, firstly you'll add fonts by using `.lib-font-face mixin` inside `_typography.less` file multiple times as required:

```
.lib-font-face(
@family-name:'my-primary-font',
@font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/path_to_file',
@font-weight: font_weight,
@font-style: font_style
);
.lib-font-face(
@family-name:'my-secondary-font',
@font-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/path_to_file',
@font-weight: font_weight,
@font-style: font_style
```

);

you can use these fonts by introducing new variables where required:

```
@font-family-name__base:'my-primary-font';
@font-family__base: @font-family-name__base, @font-family__sans-serif;
@font-family-name__secondary-font:'mysecondaryfontname';
@font-family__secondary: @font-family-name__secondary-font, @font-family__secondary-fallback-font;
```

Now `@font-family__base` and `@font-family__secondary` variables can be used where required in your css (less).

**Note** you only need to provide the path where all required font files are located without providing any extension, mixin will load all files for you.

Comment: How to add 2 or more fonts?

Comment: I've just edited above to answer your question

Comment: When I do this, it tries to load the font but the font files don't seem to be put anywhere in pub/static so they 404

Comment: Do I need to import lib-font-face?

Answer (score 0):

If your theme does not use the Magento UI library, include the font in your theme `.css` files by the standard means of CSS, for example the `@font-face` rule.I've created `mytheme.less` file in `web/css/` path and i than created `_font-face.less` file and `import` it in `mytheme.less`. I placed my font declaration using normal syntax with extension to it. Please change `src:url` accordingly.

**_font-face.less**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Regular';
    src:url('../fonts/Gilroy-Regular.eot?387osh');
    src:url('../fonts/Gilroy-Regular.eot?#iefix387osh') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/Gilroy-Regular.woff?387osh') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/Gilroy-Regular.ttf?387osh') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I've that file as css included in my `<theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml` file in head tag. [ see how to include custom css file in magento 2]

**default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<css src="css/mytheme.css" order="100"/>
```

Than you will be able to your font-faces everywhere in your theme.